# Compare aspect ratios given width and height

Tags: c++, aspect-ratio

Given a list of screen sizes, how do I detect which ones are in 4:3 16:9 aspect ratio?
I can use width / height to get it but for 16:9 sizes I sometimes get 1.778 and sometimes I get 1.777778 due to rounding errors.

Comment: 4:3 and 16:9 are different enough so you can round it to one decimal and still get it right. So don't worry about lost precision, just round it to one or two decimals.

Comment: Also be sure to check whether the screen mode has a pixel aspect ratio -- in which case it needs to be multiplied to the resolution ratio to get the screen aspect ratio.

Comment: Also, be prepared for interesting ratios. My desktop expands across two monitors, giving it 32:9 ratio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if `4 * height == 3 * width` or `16 * height == 9 * width`.

Remember the definition of a *rational number*: It is an equivalence class of pairs of integers (*m*, *n*) sub­ject to the equivalence (*m*, *n*) ≡ (*m*', *n*') if and only if *n*' *m* = *n* *m*'.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the rounding to be always the same, and then you can compare the values:

```
float ratio = (int)((width / height) * 100);
```

You will get always 177 for 16:9 and 133 for 4:3

good luck

Answer (score 0):

compare with some epsilon proximity.

should be something like:

```
double epsilon = 0.01;
if(math.abs(screen1.height/screen1.width - screen2.height/screen2.width) < epsilon)
{
//equal ratios
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use an epsilon value for the comparison.
You can have a look at: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm